Mylatexformat in Windows and Mac
I precompile my preamble using Mylatexformat.
Since I work on a Mac and a PC it would be great if the same file could be compiled on both systems.
It works great on my PC using this:
%&C:\Users\foo\mylatexformat
\endofdump
Non-precompiled build works on the Mac, but when I use mylatexformat and change the first line to
%&/Users/foo/mylatexformat
then I get an error and it seems that the .fmt file is just not found...
So I got 2 questions:

Did I do something wrong with the Mac there?
Is there any way to make that switch automatic so that I do not need to change the first line?

I am using miktex and xetex and Texstudio on both systems.
Command: xelatex -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -synctex=1 -output-driver="xdvipdfmx -z0 -V7" %.tex

you've tagged this miktex. are you using miktex on both systems and xetex in both cases? what command are you using to produce the format? what does 'doesn't work' mean? do you get an error when you try to create it, when you try to use it or what?

Sorry for the incomplete post. I added the info you asked for.

so the pre-compiled format compiles on the mac? the problem is when you use it? I've never thought it worth bothering to do this, but post the log from a failed attempt to compile a simple hello, world document on the mac. and always paste the exact error message. this will have context info like line number etc.

Why not put the format in a folder where it is usually found and simply use %&myformat? To get the search path for format files, use kpsewhich -show-path=fmt (I hope MiKTeX supports this, otherwise see the MiKTeX documentation about where is searchs for format files — or use TeXLive instead of MiKTeX).
